# openstack: how to run multiple glance instances?

Tags: openstack

I'm new to openstack. And I have followed the installation guide to set an openstack on a single host server. Now I got a question. On the single node, I registered a glance service and relative endpoints in keystone. If I want to run glance on multiple host servers, do I need to register two glance services in keystone? Or do I still just need one glance service but add more glance endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to find a way to load balance the glace API endpoints then place the load balanced address into the keystone catalog as a PublicURL.

The trick is finding a way to load balance glance.  The big issues is the size of queries to glance in both time and data throughput.  Not exactly an easy service to load balance.

Comment: Matt, thanks for your answer. If I run glance on two nodes, should I define one glance service but add two endpoints in keystone? As my understanding, glance is used by nova, dose nova has the ability to automatically share load to the two glance nodes? Furthermore, how the two glance nodes share image?

Comment: nova queries keystone for the catalog to find the API url for glance.  If you wish to load blance the BACKEND api queries you'd need to use the Internal URL in the catalog to set the loadbalancer endpoint.  Of course you will no doubt have some networking complexity to deal with.

Comment: You can easily stash multiple glance endpoints behind an F5 or a software LB like HAProxy, and it works reasonably well. You need to watch the timeouts, but that lets you balance the requests and have a single endpoint in keystone that all the clients easily grok.